# react native, как снять focus с textInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Есть TextInput, и кнопка отмены, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, с textInput снимался фокус?

Comment: На сколько помню событие `focus` срабатывает при фокусировке на поле, а `blur` когда фокус исчезает, например посетитель кликает на другом месте экрана.

Answer (score 2):

Решил:

```
<TextInput
ref='searchInput'
/>
```

Событие на кнопку:

```
onPress={(event) => { 
  this.refs.searchInput.blur() 
  this.refs.searchInput.setNativeProps({text: ''})
}}
```